# Why stream isn't limited, is there is filter() before limit()?

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I was surprised to figure out, that when I had added filter block, limit block stopped working - stream stayed infinite.
See an example code

```
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

class A {
    private static final long MAX_DAYS = 9;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.now();
        Set<LocalDate> bankWorkDays = new HashSet<>();
        bankWorkDays.add(startDate.plusDays(1));
        bankWorkDays.add(startDate.plusDays(2));
        bankWorkDays.add(startDate.plusDays(4));
        bankWorkDays.add(startDate.plusDays(5));
        final List<LocalDate> workDays = Stream.iterate(startDate, localDate -> localDate.plusDays(1))
                .filter(bankWorkDays::contains)
                .limit(MAX_DAYS)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
/*
    final List<LocalDate> workDays = new ArrayList<>();
    long limit = overdueDaysRange;
    for (LocalDate localDate = startDate; ; localDate = localDate.plusDays(1)) {
        if (bankWorkDays.contains(localDate)) {
            if (limit-- == 0) break;
            workDays.add(localDate);
        }
    }
*/
    }
}
```

In the comments block I paste code that was generated when I asked my IDE to transform this code to the equivalent loop.

I don't get the logic why can't stream first generate value, then filter it if needed and after that check, that total amount of elements of stream so far is still less than limit value?

Comment: I've just runned your code, but didn't loop... what's the problem?

Comment: are you sure this is the example you ran? and also what *exactly* is the problem here?

Comment: I've cut that snippet from my project, but everything looks the same. Let me check that everything important is copied

Comment: https://ideone.com/zrl8aB

Comment: updated code snippet. Constant MAX_DAYS should be greater than size of Set

Comment: now that you've edited your post. look into the doc for [`Stream.iterate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#iterate-T-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-)

Comment: @Aominè, I have read javadoc, still no clue XD

Comment: `Stream.iterate` returns an infinite stream and since the number of elements that pass the `filter` operation is not `9` the stream will carry on to process elements.

Comment: I've got it! The problem is not with the stream, it's with the logic. As there is only 4 dates in Set, there cannot be more than 4 elements in this stream, and every value after startDate.plusDays(5) produced by Stream.iterate(startDate, localDate -> localDate.plusDays(1)) is skipped

Comment: @Aominè, Yeah, imperative approach code was generated by IDE, as I said.